# Ubuntu + Sil 3114 Satalink install

Tags: boot, drivers, pci

So (Linux noobish)

I have installed Ubuntu Server x64 on an old AMD Athlon 64 and it is running fine and does exactly what I wanted it for. BUT I need to install some more DVD drives (adding 4 more) so I bought a Sata PCI card which has the SIL 3114 chip.

If I boot and install Ubuntu with the card in it installs fine and all is happy, until I reboot and then it will POST but not start Ubuntu, (just a flashing cursor at the top left), but if I take the card out it will boot and run fine.

Now I'm guessing that the drivers are not installed for the card hence why it will not boot. Can anyone advise on how I can check to see if the drivers are installed OR how to install the from the internet.

Comment: Try booting the Ubuntu Live Desktop DVD and see if it boots with the SATA card installed.

Comment: ps: you've got an old card. You might check http://www.latticesemi.com/Support/ASSPSoftwareArchive.aspx?ActiveTab=Drivers#_48C18C3AA9EA443BAECE41C7B96650E6 for a firmware update. There are two listed.

Comment: ps2: when the ubuntuforums.org come back online you might also check https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjBmNSarsLSAhXGjFQKHVqYA6EQFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fubuntuforums.org%2Fshowthread.php%3Ft%3D915745&usg=AFQjCNEeBTbGRUWx25E59-ujfyZGl-EGGw&sig2=6F2pyQUOYp_bO0l5ODmWjA&bvm=bv.148747831,d.cGw&cad=rja

Comment: Great I'll have a look at those

Comment: ps3: if you're going to run DVD drives, you'll want to install the `base` firmware, NOT the `RAID` firmware.

Comment: HI @davidfoerster. I have removed the cross post as requested

Comment: @heynnema I can boot with the PCI card in and the Live Ubuntu works and sees all the DVD drives.

Comment: I have just done a fresh download of Ubuntu Server 16.10.x and done a fresh install on the box with the PCI card installed and no other cards. I still get the same issue upon boot. here is a video
https://youtu.be/p05AgH7rU1g
I don't get a chance to run any commands as it is not even getting that far into the boot process

Comment: Sry Server 16.04.x

Comment: I have also just tried to install the desktop version and I get the same problem. Im just so baffled as to why does the Live version work but the installed version does not

Comment: Are there any BIOS settings that you need to change to identify what kind of devices are connected to what ports? SCSI/ATA/IDE or tape/disk/DVD/etc?

Comment: @heynnema after the initial pc bios the sil 3114 bios shows  the version on its firmware 5.5.x and it detects the 2 DVD drives attached. When I boot using a live USB disk it sees all 3 DVD drives attached. 1 ide and 2 sata which all detect the disks inside them (just audio cds). It's just really odd as if it was stopping the pc booting I wouldn't be able to install the os either live or native but it gets through all of those and then won't boot which leaves me with it is missing a driver or something.